# Django ORM INNER JOIN

Tags: python, django, orm, django-models

I have not been able to do this query with Django ORM. 
how to make a inner join, how to do this query and return only the columns I want?

```
SELECT     establecimiento.nombre, categoria.titulo
FROM         establecimiento INNER JOIN
                      categoria ON establecimiento.categoria = categoria.id
```

Comment: Can you show your model definitions? This is very simple if you have a proper `ForeignKey` field declared between the two models.

Comment: How I can make a simple INNER JOIN in Django ,because I made this in sql but I can't make this query in Django, How I can work with two models from Django ORM

Comment: possible duplicate of [django query with ...objects.raw](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21359710/django-query-with-objects-raw)

Comment: Didn't I just answer this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21359710/django-query-with-objects-raw/21360185)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the information in your comment responding to pdxwebdev (that you have a foreign key field declared) this is simple. Django automates much of the join behavior needed for foreign key relationships.

To precisely replicate that query, including selecting only two fields from the join, any of `values`, `values_list` or `only` should do it depending on exactly what Python objects you want to get back. Eg, here's a query using `values` to retrieve an iterable queryset of dictionaries:

```
Establecimiento.objects.values('nombre', 'categoria__titulo')
```

`values_list` will retrieve tuples instead of dictionaries, and `only` will retrieve `Establecimiento` instances on which all model fields other than those two are deferred (they have not been retrieved from the database but will be looked up as needed).

When you use `__` to follow a foreign key relationship like that, Django will do the inner join automatically.

You can also use `select_related` on a queryset to ask it to do the join even when you're not retrieving specific fields. EG:

```
Establecimiento.objects.select_related('categoria')
```

This should produce a query of `SELECT * from ...`, and return a queryset of `Establecimiento` instances that have their `categoria` data already loaded into memory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question. 
establecimiento.categoria just needs to be a foreign key field to categoria model. categoria.id is the primary key so this will be done automatically.

To return only certain columns, just the .only() method.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#only

Comment: I have two models:Establecimiento and Categoria, The Establecimiento Model has a ForeignKey(Categoria). Then I want show the Establecimiento's name and the Categoria's name  of the relation .