# django query with ...objects.raw

Tags: django, django-models, inner-join

How I can make a query with two models using this 
 model.objects.raw(...)
and into the sql query has the INNER JOIN with the another model(table) this is possible

```
model.objects.raw('
SELECT     establecimiento.nombre, categoria.titulo
FROM         establecimiento INNER JOIN
                      categoria ON establecimiento.categoria = categoria.id')
```

I need print the establecimiento's name with his  categoria's name

```
class Establecimiento(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length = 140)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria)
    ciudad = models.ForeignKey(Ciudad)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre



class Categoria(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length = 140)
```

Comment: Please post your models. You need to use the django ORM. `objects.raw` is not for such queries.

Comment: I made  the query with (model.objects.raw) because I have problems with ORM django and for this  reason .I'm trying to do it with a sql query into the ...objects.raw
What  is the best solution?
You can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetching objects from the ORM automatically does any joins required and will return objects  (instances of the models) which you can use to follow relationships.

If you simply fetch all your `Establecimiento` objects, you can access the related `Categoria` objects, like this:

```
all_objects = Establecimiento.objects.all()

for obj in all_objects:
   print('Number: {} Category: {}'.format(obj.nombre, obj.categoria.titulo))
```

Or, if you want to fetch *only* those two specific properties, use [`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#values), like this:

```
all_objects = Establecimiento.objects.values('nombre','ciudad__titulo')
for obj in all_objects:
   print('Number: {} Category: {}'.fromat(obj['nombre'],obj['ciudad__titulo']))
```